# Editar conteúdo da Div

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, input

Tenho uma `index`, que exibe os dados do meu banco de dados, queria que ao clicar em cima da `div`, abrisse um modal, que permitisse alterar aquele valor da `div`.

Código da `view`:

```
<div style="float:left; max-width:200px;max-height:200px;" class="text-center alteracor">
     <b>Salário</b><br />
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Salario)
</div>
```

Layout da `view`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na sua `div` coloque uma classe para alterar o valor, por exemplo:

```
<div style="float:left; max-width:200px;max-height:200px;" class="text-center alteracor alterarValor">
     <b>Salário</b><br />
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Salario)
</div>
```

Coloque uma `div` para abrir o modal:

```
<div id="modal-container-alterar-valor"></div>
```

Pelo JavaScript você faz a chamada para abrir o modal:

```
$('body').on('click', '.alterarValor', function (e) {
    var url = '@Url.Action("AlterarValor", "SeuController")';
        var params = { salario: "@Model.Salario" };
        $.post(url, params, function (data) {
            $('#modal-container-alterar-valor').html(data);
            $('#modal-alterar-valor').modal();
        });
    });
});
```

No controller, coloque a chamada da partial:

```
public PartialViewResult AlterarValor(double valorAlterado)
{
    return PartialView("_AlterarValorModal", new SeuModelo { ValorAlterado = valorAlterado });
}
```

Crie uma partial para o conteúdo do modal, por exemplo:

```
@Html.Modal(new Modal {
    Id = "modal-alterar-valor",
    Titulo = "Alterar Valor",
    IdForm = "frm-alterar-valor",
},
    @<text>    
         <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
             @Html.Label("Informe o novo valor")
             @Html.InputGroup("valorAlterar", "", new { @class = "form-control mask-decimal" })
         </div>     
     </text>,
@<text>
    <button id="btnAlterarValorOk" class="btn btn-default" data-action="@Url.Action("AlterarValor")">OK</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
</text>)
```